# Android Animation Background (Rotate, Translate)

Tags: android, background, rotation, translate-animation

I make my first small game. I use the Rotate Animation, that was given from Android. 
I write this code in every class file:

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate, R.anim.translate);
```

is this the best way or can I set this up somewhere for my whole app?
And also, if I use this animation, the new Activity "rotates" into the screen very nice but the background gets black. (I think because of the translate animation?!) How can I set up my own Background?

the code from the translate animation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate>

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="200%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="200%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
```

and the rotate animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="-5%"
    android:pivotY="5%p"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### Abstraction

The current way you have it:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate, R.anim.translate);
```

The best way to set this is either via an abstract `Activity` or [composition](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html) which is more to do with programming practice than Android specifically.

The short being:

```
public abstract BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity{
  @Override
  protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate, R.anim.translate);
  }
}
```

Then your concrete `Activity` extends this.

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{}
```

### Animation

So the current setup means that your New `Activity` will Rotate **in**, and your old activity (should) translate **out**.

Seen as your translating your old activity out (not in) the animation is a bit wrong.
A correct translate animation for translating out would be something like:

```
<translate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXDelta="0%"
  android:toXDelta="100%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%"
  android:toYDelta="0%"
  android:duration="1000" />
```

Which will translate the exiting activity from centre screen to slide to the right.

Also ignore the `zAdjustment`, by default your new activity starts on top of the old one, you dont want to leave the old on top.